# primefaces datatable filter between dates

Tags: date, jsf-2, primefaces, filter, filtering

i need to filter some fields between dates, but primefaces does not have support for date filtering yet.

i can do it with a function but im not sure how... here is some example  i found:

```
<f:facet name="header">DateRange
  <div>
    <p:calendar id="from" value="#{bean.from}" styleClass="calendarFilter">
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{ctrlr.filterDates()}" update="dataTableId"/>
    </p:calendar>
    <p:calendar id="to" value="#{bean.to}" styleClass="calendarFilter">
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{ctrlr.filterDates()}" update="dataTableId"/>
    </p:calendar>
  </div>
</f:facet>
```

there is only the "view" code, id like to see how it would be the filtering function in my bean.

any example would be welcome :)

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PF Filtering a Datatable column which contains a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846128/pf-filtering-a-datatable-column-which-contains-a-date)

Answer (score 3):

There were I would keep the date fields in a different output panel and based on date select update the table on click of a filter button.

```
<h:outputText value="FROM" />
<p:calendar id="strtdt" showOn="button" title="Start Date" size="12"            value="#{form.startDate}" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true">
</p:calendar>
<h:outputText value="TO" />
<p:calendar id="enddt" showOn="button" title="End Date" size="12" value="#{form.endDate}"
navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true" >
</p:calendar>
<p:commandButton id="btnFilter" value="Filter" update="datatable"  action="#{controller.update()}" ajax="true" />
```

In the Controller Class write the code to fetch the required data between the dates and update the table (or the list that loads the table).
Hope this helps.