# Primefaces dataTable filtering with date

Tags: date, jsf-2, primefaces, filter, datatable

I came accross a particular problem. I have a datatable in which i want to filter dates in primefaces. when I use

```
<p:column id="date" headerText="Manufacturing date" 
    filterBy="#{car.dateOfManufacturing}" 
    filterMatchMode="contains">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{car.dateOfManufacturing}"  >
    </p:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

Then the filtering of dates happen fine. But when i use

```
<p:column id="date" headerText="Manufacturing date" 
    filterBy="#{car.dateOfManufacturing}" 
    filterMatchMode="contains">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{car.dateOfManufacturing}"  >
        <f:convertDateTime locale="de"  />
    </p:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

the filtering does not happen properly. In fact my observation is with the locale the date format is something like

20.11.2013

but even if I type Wed Nov .. i am able to see filtered results.
I also observed that without locale the date is dispayed as

Wed Nov 20 13:43:37 CET 2013
 So i guess it is getting filtered according the latter date even though we see a different date pattern on the screen.

Comment: What is type of car.dateOfManufacturing field? Simple date? If it is one way format this date to string...

Comment: I am currently using java.util.Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think need to convert your date before add to filter (`filterBy="#{car.dateOfManufacturing}"`). One of the simple solution is convert date to string with simple date format in bean.

Here is my code:

My **RowData** containts: `String entry1, String entry2, String dateString, Date date`.

My bean method for fill data:

```
public List<RowData> getTestData() {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
(...)
  entries.add(new RowData("a1", "b1", dateFormat.format(new Date()), currentDate()));
(...)
return entries;
```

and my XHTML:

```
<p:column id="date" headerText="Simple date"
                    filterBy="#{entry.dateString}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
         <p:outputLabel value="#{entry.dateString}"  >
         </p:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

Now I add your code to my table:

```
<p:column id="dateLocale" headerText="Locale date"
                          filterBy="#{entry.date}"
                          filterMatchMode="contains">
         <p:outputLabel value="#{entry.date}"  >
            <f:convertDateTime locale="de"  />
         </p:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

My table:

[image]

Filtering works fine with these three date in locale date column. Perhaps, if I start test this issue with many date, the result will be same which described in your answer.

So, I offer covert date to string or [use calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10846151/1047582).